# Could not find the matplotlib module. Make sure the matplotlib is installed

Tags: qgis, matplotlib

When I open my QGIS this message is open :

> Could not find the matplotlib module. Make sure the matplotlib is
> installed.

I am trying to install the matplotlib through OSGeo shell (windows system) but it is not successful.
I will use SCP and matplotlib is required.

C:\OSGeo4W>py3_env
'py3_env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also tried python console but not successful

Comment: Try `C:\OSGeo4W> o4w_env` instead of `py3_env`. The batch file was renamed from QGIS 3.20. For reference, it is in the `\bin` subdirectory.